# alternative and sequetial structure algorithms

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages

I want to know the definition and difference between alternative and sequetial structure algorithms.
I know what is the sequential structure algorithm but if someone can define it more simpler,
And i have not found anything about the alternative one.

Comment: Seems "alternative"  is not common term in algorithmics. Perhaps you do mean random access structures?

Comment: It might help if you explain or link and explanation of sequential structure algorithms. Do you mean sequential algorithms (in contrast to parallel algorithms)?

Comment: @MBo: like an `if` statement. A third kind is the *repetititve* construct, i.e. the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a sequential structure, you perform all instructions one after the other, inconditionally.

In an alternative structure, you select the one to be executed, based on activation conditions.

(In the Hoare formalism, when several instructions have a true condition, one is chosen non-deterministically.)